# Что означает данное уведомление?

Tags: android-studio

Появляется такая ошибка при попытке синхронизации проекта в Android Studio

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Означает, что верхнего пути нет или туда нет доступа.

Comment: Внизу написано, что Android Studio использует SDK по указанному там пути, а не потому пути, что указан сверху